# Navigate back to app after open login page on browser from app

Tags: java, android, kotlin, google-oauth, deep-linking

I want to login my user with login url, which have option to login with google. After login with google, i want my user to get back to app with callback of logged in success or failure to change app behavior[![enter image description here][1]][1]

For reference you can check **NordVpn** signIn feature

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nordvpn.android

Comment: If you're using the Navigation component, the whole login scenario is covered here: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-conditional

Comment: login feature is being handle by web developer, i need to navigate to browser to login and after successful login navigate back to app with response of user logged in successfully

Comment: @SandeepKumar did you manage to do that? i need to do something similar on my end and i am kinda lost

Comment: @chgsilva i have update answer below, you can check

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this, you need to implement deep links like below

`android:scheme` this key is important, scheme should not have https://, because its behavior is look for browser app in android device, scheme should be unique to only your app (consider using appName) and webapp should to navigate to url like
`randomApp://openApp......`

```
 <activity
            android:name=".ui.activity.DeepLinkingActivity"
            android:exported="true">

            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="randomApp" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
```

Below is reference image from Android documentation on Deep Links (https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking)
app scheme is unique to our app only and it should not used by another app

**NOTE: If two apps using same scheme value then android will give choice user and user can select which app they want to navigate**

[image]